# How do I launch a splash screen for every launch in React Navigation V5?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, splash-screen, react-navigation-v5

I want to launch `SplashScreen`, for every App launch where I'll be performing a large number of tasks. Once this is done, I'll navigate to `AuthScreen` or `MainScreen`.

Since there is no `SwitchNavigator` in V5. How do I achieve the following conditions,

1. `AuthScreen`: When a user clicks the Android hardware back button, he has to exit the App without going back to `SplashScreen`.
2. `MainScreen`: Same scenario as above, When a user clicks the Android hardware back button, he has to exit the App.

I can place `SplashScreen` inside `<RootStack.Navigator/>` making SplashScreen as `initialRouteName` but it didn't satisfy the above conditions.

Can anyone help me out where should I place the `SplashScreen` component in V5?

Here is the `AppNavigation.js` file

```
const RootStackScreen = ({ userStatus }) => {
    return (
        <RootStack.Navigator headerMode="none">
            {userStatus ? (
                <RootStack.Screen name="AppDrawerScreen" component={AppDrawerScreen} />
            ) : (
                <RootStack.Screen name="AuthStackScreen" component={AuthStackScreen} />
            )}
        </RootStack.Navigator>
    );
};

const AppContainer = ({ user }) => {
    return (
        <NavigationContainer>
            <RootStackScreen userStatus={user} />
        </NavigationContainer>
    );
};
```

Comment: Ok I found the answer in the docs https://reactnavigation.org/docs/auth-flow#define-our-screens